# Can anyone explain this 'variable does not exist error'?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a test class which calls a method from a helper class :

```
@isTest
private class OpportunityCheckTest {

    private CheckTestHelper helper = new CheckTestHelper();

    @isTest
    static void checkTest() {

        helper.incrementCount();  <-- ERROR INDICATES THIS LINE

    }
}
```

At the moment when I try to save my file, I'm getting the following error:

```
Result: [DEPLOYMENT FAILED]: OpportunityCheckTest.cls: Variable does not exist: helper
```

Can anyone explain what the problem is here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method is static, but helper was defined as a non-static member variable.

To fix it, make helper static:

```
static CheckTestHelper helper = new CheckTestHelper();
```

To keep things straight, remember that there's only one static element in memory at a time, while non-static elements can only be contained inside an *instance* of an object.

Static members can't access non-static variables and methods (which instance would the static method access?), but non-static code can reference static code and data (because there's ever only a single copy in memory).

Comment: Cheers sfdcfox, much appreciated!